# Simply trying to add another layer to openlayers3 script

Tags: javascript, wms, openlayers

I'm simply trying to add new layers with each as their own variable so I can turn them on and off, instead of just stacking all the layers under the variable `layers`.

See script below

```
<script>
var layers = [
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})
  }),
];

var poly1 = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
      params: {'LAYERS': 'sample:sample', 'TILED': true},
      serverType: 'geoserver',
    })
  });

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: poly1, layers,
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [lat, lon],
    zoom: 4
  })
});
</script>
```

For some reason when add more than one layer to the layers line of code here

```
var map = new ol.Map({
layers: poly1, layers,
```

they both will not display, if I have one of the other they work, but can't get more than one variable working... I assume this is a simple syntax error but has me stumped and cannot seem to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

`layers` config accepts an ol.Collection or a js array.
try this

```
var map = new ol.Map({
layers: [poly1, layers],
```

Comment: Cheers for the reply, I've decided though to switch from openlayers to leaflet